# JSON Parsing a Redis.get return

Tags: ruby, redis

I'm storing some data in Redis and when I retrieve this data I'm having trouble parsing it.

When I run this:

`$redis.get("data")` I get this: `"[{\"login\"=>\"name\", \"id\"=>1574}]"`

When I try to use JSON.parse against the return body I get this error:

`JSON::ParserError: 409: unexpected token at '{"login"=>"name", "id"=>1574}]'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you consider using RedisJSON.io?

Comment: That's not JSON. It looks like a Ruby hash inside of an array that was naïvely converted to a string instead of encoded as JSON before being put into the database. The culprit is whatever code is writing to Redis, not the code that's reading from it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to first serialize your ruby object into JSON before storing it in redis.

In this case you would need to call `$redis.set('data', JSON.dump(data))` instead of what is currently being called, which is `$redis.set('data', data.to_s)`. The `.to_s` gets called on whatever object is passed into redis' `set` method.

If you really need to parse the data you have already stored then you can use ruby's `eval`, although you should not use this in production!

```
$ data = eval($redis.get('data'))
=> [{"login"=>"name", "id"=>1574}]
$ $redis.set('data', JSON.dump(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"[{\"login\"=>\"name\", \"id\"=>1574}]"
```

is not json string

---

If you want to deserialize string then you write this.

```
"[{\"login\":\"name\", \"id\":1574}]"
```

`=>` is changed to `:`

So, you need to modify the creation JSON string.